# Android how to get bounds of imageview with matrix

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, scale, bounds

I have an ImageView with scaletype set to matrix, and would like to get a Rect with the bounds of the image after the transformation of the matrix.

How do I get such a rect? thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
Rect imageBounds = drawable.getBounds();
```

Then use Matrix.mapRect.

Comment: So, complete code for me was
`Rect bounds = imageView.getDrawable().getBounds();
RectF boundsF = new RectF(bounds);
imageView.getImageMatrix().mapRect(boundsF);
boundsF.round(bounds);`

Thank you, it worked and I finally fixed a transition!

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
```

Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
Rect imageBounds = drawable.getBounds();

this is wrong, this will get the original drawable bound, not the really bound
of bitmap drawn on ImageView