# Is there anyway to get the Rect in which Bitmap is drawn on Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I am trying to subclass `ImageView` and draw something on `Bitmap`. However I cannot find a way to get the `Rect` in which `Bitmap` is drawn. I can only get the `Rect` in which `ImageView` is drawn by `getDrawingRect(Rect)` method of `ImageView`. Below is an illustration of what I want to get:

[image]

The Rect I want is the blue one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the rectangle of the Drawable of ImageView on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987580/how-to-get-the-rectangle-of-the-drawable-of-imageview-on-android)

Comment: I want to draw a rectangle which user can move and resize to crop the image.

Answer (score 3):

The given image will be drawn in the ImageView based on the attributes given e.g., height, width, scaling factors, etc.

So that the **getDrawingRect()** method giving the entire area of ImageView. If you change the drawable inside ImageView the blue colored area may change based on the image properties and imageview properties. But the yellow colored area won't change because it is fixed and based on the ImageView only, its independent of image displayed.

I think no chance to get the Rect of bitmap drawn. Don't think my answer is 100% correct, it is just a suggestion only.

You may get information about blue colored area from **Drawing Cache**. Try it once.

I hope it may help you.